EFT (IEC 61000-4-4:Burst Test) Fail. I used SPI Interface
I am using TI ADC part# ADS131E08 and STM MCU Part# STM32H7 Series.
#3 channel : Voltage measurement (3phase)
#3 channel : Current measurement (3phase)
#1 chanel : Internal-zero current measurement.
#1 chanel : External-zero current measurement.
#External Clock Frequency= 2.048 MHz
#Analog ground and digital ground are not split on ADC IC
SPI I/F config.  see below
DRDY : 8kHz
Speed: 16MHz
Here is result is the tests about EMC.
Surge Test : 4kV Passed
Burst Test(EFT: IEC 61000-4-4) : 1kV Passed,  2kV Failed.  (Both 5kHz and 100kHz)
 does not mean that the IC or product is damaged.
It means that the ADC measurement value changes and operates abnormally.

The ESD Level (HBM, CDM) is lower than other parts. Can this affect the burst immunity test?

*ESD voltage of ADC131E08 listed in Datahseet appears to be around 500V.

Datasheet says that ground split is not mandantory . Could it be a problem if it is used as a common ground(=not split condition)?

When communicating with the main MCU and ADC IC, a issue occurs with the measured value, If remove the ADC IC you won't have any problems. (=burst tests passed up to 4kV)


For this reason, I think it is a problem with the ADC IC block and not a problem with the product.
It is unknown whether it is a problem with the Analog Input and Reference voltage or common ground, or a problem with the digital square wave in the SPI Line.

The Main MCU is in PCBA-1, and the ADC IC is in PCBA-2. It two pcba are connected by a shielded cable. it call FPCB. it's not FFC.

Here is FPCB Pin and Line config.
GND/12V/GND/3.3V/GND/DRDR/GND/CLK/GND/MISO/GND/MOSI/GND/START_ADC/GND/RESET_ADC/GND...etc.

Totally tracce length is around 100mm from STM32 H7 to TI ADC IC

Reference voltage is 1.65V and a resolution of 24 bits is used.
PCB is 6 Layers.
TOP (1-Layer) - Placement + signal (short trace and/or others trace.) with copper
IN-1 (2-Layer) - Power plane (12V/3.3V/12V/VCM. there not gnd copper. Power only layer)
IN-2 (3-Layer) - GROUND PLANE
IN-3 (4-Layer) - Signal Layer
IN-4 (5-Layer) - GROUND PLANE
BTM (6-Layer) - Placement + signal (short trace and/or others trace.) with copper
Only through-hole vias were used and no anti-pad setting was used, so the grounds of all layers are connected.
Shuld I additional ESD Coponents? or should I chaged PCB Design? or other things?
I can't find about solution.  Is it conducted noise or radiated noise?
Thanks in advance

EFT is carried into the board by connections. What external connections are on your board? (Please list all, and at least a basic description of their purpose, and what types of nets/voltages/signals are used within each.) What are they connected to, in the test? Finally, what could be affected by noise coming up these connectors: what is the schematic and PCB layout?

PCB1(Main MCU, ETHERNET IC, MAC IC, Buck converter, LDO),   PCB2(Analog input(Current, Voltage, ADC IC), PCB3(POWER PCB witn isolated flyback converter). each PCBs are connected through FPCB. I'm making a product that measures voltage and current, and the measured voltage and current fluctuate at 2kV EFT. (Voltage and current are measured even though they are not applied.)

You can edit your question to include relevant information and updates. Comments are for discussion, and are easily lost; don't add updates here. To increase the chance of getting good answers, include a diagram of your system, and schematics and PCB layout.
